# Maven 2 project versions, dependency versions, and perpetual releasing

Tags: version-control, maven-2

Scenario: The system has number of components, each with its own POM.  There are some long dependency chains (A depends on B depends on C, etc.).  I want each "non-developer-desktop" build to be a potential release candidate -- if it passes QA, we will deploy it without rebuilding.  In other words, I never want to build SNAPSHOT versions as part of my regularly scheduled builds, only versions like 1.3.0.5, 1.3.0.6, etc.  I also want to enable the developers to work on multiple components at once.

To forestall some expected suggestions: the Maven Release Plugin doesn't help me ... unless there's some magic way I can have my dependency versions not be SNAPSHOTs in the POMs but still let the developers work on more than one component at once?

**How should we manage the project and dependency versions in all of our our POMs?**  Right now it's just SNAPSHOTs everywhere, which makes things simple for the developers (they started with SNAPSHOTs and never concerned themselves with anything else).  But it's worrying at deployment time (builds with SNAPSHOT dependencies are not well-defined, and not reproducible).

I'd like to avoid excessive juggling at build time, but right now I don't see any way around it.

Let's say I have components util, libj, libk, APP, and UI, with dependencies as follows:

libj -> util (libj depends on util)

libk -> util

APP -> libj

UI -> libj, libk

I have development teams working on APP and UI, and they will sometimes need to make changes/additions to some of the dependencies (even util) in order to enable their current work.  How should the checked-in POM and dependency versions for each component look?

Edit: I updated the title to refer to Maven 2 instead of 2.0, since it became apparent that I would need to work with 2.1 or better in order to best resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to layout your builds such that modules that need to be developed together are released together. This will let the maven release plugin do most of the work for you.

For dependencies that really should have a separate lifecyle...because they change infrequently or are shared by multiple projects, you want to handle those differently. They way I do it is to keep the dependencies at the last release version until a change actually requires an upgrade to the next snapshot. In this way when you go to release the product, you will find all the things that may also be released simply by following the snapshot trails.

I find it also helpful to keep the external dependency versions specified as properties in the top pom of my project. This makes it easy to see at a glance what needs to be released. Look for an example of the [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org) pom.

Comment: I want "release the product" to be automated as-needed.  Having an unpredictable set of snapshot dependencies would make that difficult, but it will usually be unnecessary (because I'll just be working from a newer "release" instead).  The first part ("modules developed together are released together") is what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to do some variation of this solution ... it seems I'll need to be using Maven 2.1 or higher in order for the release plugin to work the way I need it to for the first part.  I'm not sure how the scm part will shake out, but it has become clear that this is the "true way".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is something I find very difficult with maven and internal projects; you have two version control systems (maven's, which, quite frankly, isn't very good) and your source code control's (which, assuming it's CVS or better, supports real workflow).

Here's how we do it:

```
report --depends on--> core
web    --depends on--> core
```

We use the maven release plug:

report's pom, during development, would have a SNAPSHOT version matching what's in core's pom.  I do a `mvn clean install` in core, then I can see those changes in `report` in my local environment.

When I do a release of report, I must first release core via the maven release plug.  When I  I use it on core, it asks me to set the version of core to release (i.e. remove the -SNAPSHOT), to which I say yes, and the resulting released artifact doesn't depend on a SNAPSHOT release.  When the release plugin is done, the report pom now depends on the next SNAPSHOT release of core (though you can override this during `mvn release:prepare` if you want).

The devs on web then get an email that a new version of core is available and they can choose to use it if they wish.  Our policy is that they should update before releasing.

Comment: Say last releases were report 2.0 --> core 1.5.  Checked-in poms: report 2.1-SNAPSHOT-->1.5; core 1.6-SNAPSHOT. Devs want to update both, change report to depend on 1.6-SN. Then, we update core to 1.6, deploy it, update it to 1.7-SN, update report to 2.1-->1.6, deploy *it*, update it to 2.2-SN? Yes?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow totally, but you might be a bit backward.  You would change and release core first, so 1.6 is released and 1.7-SNAP is the new dev version.  Then, when you mvn release:prepare report, it will set core's SNAP version to non-SNAP for you

Comment: Fine, but if the devs are wanting to confirm their changes to core are going to work with the changes to report, then what?  That's why I say that before anything else, they'd need to update the report pom (currently depending on 1.5) to depend on 1.6-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Well, if you are saying that core can't be released unless you know it doesn't break its dependees, that gets tricky, and is a bit backward.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that the other way around: if they want to confirm the new 'report' will work with the new 'core'.  I don't want them to have to wait for their changes to core to be released before they can work on report.

Comment: I guess you'd need to loosen the requirements for "releasing a version to the maven repo".  You could let anyone create a new point release, and maybe have a more involved review process for major/minor.

Answer (score 0):

This is really the same problem as someone needing to branch code they are working on.  You need some form of identifier to be able to get at the specific version until you merge back to the mainline development of that component.

The [dependency classifier](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) may be something worth looking into.  You'll still need to have developers that will properly identify their modified code.

Answer (score 0):

we work with a "Super Parent".pom-project, in it the versions are defined as properties and in every child.project, the versions are set with those properties

in addition the real projects have no version set, instead they inherit it from their parent pom-project (incl. groupId etc.)

with this set up the versions are only defined in some parent pom-projects, thus the needed setup is minimized

e.g. this structure

- super parent pom-project (all 3rd party versions as properties defined, e.g. 2.5.6 spring-framework)
  ---- persistence-parent pom-project, inherits all from super parent
  ------ persistence-foobar jar project, inherits all from persistence-parent
  ---- util-parent

etc.

only versions you see are the ones inside the parent relations
example:

> ```
>         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> <artifactId>foo-bar-foo</artifactId>
> <packaging>jar</packaging>
> <name>whatever</name>
> <description>...</description>
> <parent>
>     <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
>     <artifactId>persistence-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
> </parent>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>         <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
>         <version>${project.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>         <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
>         <version>${project.version}</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>org.springframework.jdbc</artifactId>
>         <version>${parent.spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

it works this way, because inside the pom you can use already defined values like version, even if the version is set via inheritance

we combine this with module setups inside the parent projects to make the builds easier